# Checking for availability of UIAppearance

Tags: iphone, ios, class, uiappearance

I'm trying to check for the availability of the UIAppearance class using:

```
NSClassFromString(@"UIAppearance")
```

However this returns nil from both iOS4 and iOS5 - anyone got any tips on how to work around this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UIAppearance is not a class, it is a protocol. So in order to check wether it exists or not, you would use:

```
NSProtocolFromString(@"UIAppearance");
```

It returns null on < iOS5, but an object on iOS5.

Answer (score 1):

This might come in handy:

[List of Classes that Support UIAppearance in iOS 5](http://blog.mosheberman.com/list-of-classes-that-support-uiappearance-in-ios-5/)