# Definitive list of classes that support the UIKit UIAppearance protocol

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uiappearance

I'm looking for a **complete list of classes that support the `UIAppearance` protocol**. I have not been able to find one. I'm open to suggestions for how to programmatically generate such a list (which I have given a tiny bit of thought to already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a definitive or complete list, but of course minutes after posting the question (by following a link to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12742945/18961)), I find this weblink:

http://blog.mosheberman.com/list-of-classes-that-support-uiappearance-in-ios-5/

There the poster used a grep command (`grep -r UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR ./ > ~/Desktop/UI_APPEARANCE.txt`) to dump out all the classes that have UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR in a method prototype. The list they came up with is as follows:

- UIActivityIndicatorView.h
- UIBarButtonItem.h
- UIBarItem.h
- UINavigationBar.h
- UIProgressView.h
- UISearchBar.h
- UISegmentedControl.h
- UISlider.h
- UISwitch.h
- UITabBar.h
- UITabBarItem.h
- UIToolbar.h

Of course, this doesn't include classes that subclass those listed above. Also, the poster mentions `UIView`, which definitely implements the protocol, but doesn't have any methods marked with `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`. I wonder if a more complete list could be created by grepping for `UIAppearance`.

Here is another related question: [iOS 5: Curious about UIAppearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257556/ios-5-curious-about-uiappearance/)

Comment: Here is an even better (more thorough grepping) answer from quite a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9424142/18961